# Is it safe to assume that $\ln{L} = -\frac{\chi^2}{2}$?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, likelihood

I have written a code that fits a 2D model image to some observed 2D image. One of the optimization libraries I use (`MultiNest`) in order to do that requires to be fed with a log likelihood calculation function. After searching on-line I read that the log-likelihood is equal to $-\frac{\chi^2}{2}$. To be honest I didn't fully understand why is that, but it seems to work just fine. And I am confident about that because I rerun all my tests using another optimizer (Levenberg-Marquardt) and I get the same (or very similar) results. So, here are my questions:

- Is it indeed correct/safe to assume that $\ln{L} = -\frac{\chi^2}{2}$?
- Is there any disadvantage in using the above method instead of calculating the likelihood properly (which I don't know how, but I guess this is a whole new question)?

Also, in case it helps, I would like to mention that I usually have many degrees of freedom (an observed image has at least 100 pixels/measurements, usually more than 500, and in many cases more than 1000). Furthermore, my models usually have 5-20 parameters.

Thank you in advance.